The manual describes a simple RaySession configuration finishing with: "The session part of the window becomes active". Not for me
I'm using Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1
I've never used RaySession before, and decided I would investigate it.
Patchance, Helvum and QPWGraph all seem to work.
RaySession quits on me before I can really get started.
